# How to get an item from redux store with redux saga

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-saga

So I have fetched the data from an API and stored it into my Redux store. It's an array of objects, containing 100ish objects. On the front end I am displaying 4 keys from every object.

What I am trying to do now is on the front end, search by a key (name or year) and render the results. Ideally, it would be something like `ILIKE` in PSQL, but even having the result only when `e.target.value === obj.super.nested.key || obj.super.nested.key_two would` be amazing.

I have tried using the `select()` from `redux-saga/effects` to no avail.

What I tried originally is on `onChange` of the input field, to dispatch an action to a watcher with the `e.target.value` as a parameter, which would call a function using that the value as a parameter for `select()`.

The code with PSQL instead of redux saga would be :

```
    const [val, setVal] = useState("");
---------------------------------------------
    useEffect(() => {
        if (val.length >= 3) {
            axios.get(`/searchCards/${val}.json`).then(results => {});
        } else if (val.length <= 3) {
            setCard("");
        }
    }, [val]);
---------------------------------------------
 function handleChange(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    setVal(e.target.value);
  }

----------------------------------------------
   <form noValidate onSubmit={e => this.submit(e)}>
            <input
              noValidate
              name="searchValue"
              placeholder="name"
              onChange={e => handleChange(e)}
            />
            <br />
            <br />
            <input onChange={e => handleChange(e)} type="date" />
          </form>
```

---

node.js

```
app.get("/searchCards/:str.json", (req, res) => {
    db.findCard(req.params.str)
        .then(results => {
            let result = results.rows[0].name;
            res.json({ result });
        })
        .catch(err => {
            console.log("error in searching for cards by name: ", err.message);
            res.json(null);
        });
});

exports.findCard = function findCard(str) {
    return db.query(`SELECT * FROM cards WHERE name ILIKE $1 LIMIT 1`, [
        str + "%"
    ]);
};
```

---

How could I achieve the same with `redux-saga`, searching the store by value, and returning the whole object which contains that value?

Comment: If you think the solution to this will be helpful to other people, you can post an answer to your own question and tick it as accepted (Which is the StackOverflow equivalent of the forum-style "SOLVED" in the title)

Comment: Putting "SOLVED" in the subject is not how StackOverflow works, nor putting a "solution" section in your question.

Answer (score 0):

I have found my workaround if anyone wants to know. The documentation on `redux-saga` is not very rich, so I did it the only way I knew how.

Basically, when the component mounts, I request the data from the api and store in the redux store. As soon as it's in the store, I render it on the FE.

Since on the change of an input field I want to display only some parts of the previously displayed data, I made a ternary which says if the input field value exists/changes, map through the store and return where input `value.toLowerCase().startsWithstartsWith(value_in_the_store)`, else, return all the data.

It works like a charm.

If anyone has another idea, I'd love to hear.